# How to add custom font in SchemDraw?

Tags: python, fonts, schemdraw

[SchemeDraw](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/start.html), python's library to draw many things, provides an option to configure global style using `schemdraw.config(font="serif")`. However, there is no mention of all the fonts supported nor how to add a custom font.

> Is there a way to add a font using .ttf file in schemdraw?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

SchemDraw uses matplotlib's fontfamily and the fonts installed in the system. In order to add a custom font using .ttf file, we have to add the font to matplotlib using its font_manager as shown below.

```
from matplotlib import font_manager

fpath = '/path/to/custom_font.ttf'
font_manager.fontManager.addfont(fpath)
```

The above snippet caches the font and then the name of the font can be used in SchemDraw directly.
For example, `schemdraw.config(font='custom')` to config the font globally for the whole drawing.

Thanks to Collin J. Delker for answering this on BitBucket. You can find the original answer [here](https://bitbucket.org/cdelker/schemdraw/issues/67/adding-custom-fonts)!